# MS Access run code on start up mystery

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access database than when opened it shows a form, however, this is not a switchboard and I can not see an Autoexec macro that is doing this. Is there any other way a designated form can be display on start up? What am I missing.

Comment: Did you check File->Options->Current Database->Display Form?

Comment: @SergeyS.Yep that is the answer. Thanks.